# New account confirmation e-mail not being sent

Tags: magento-1.9

When user create a new account the confirmation e-mail sent successfully. But the confirmation e-mail not being sent for particular e-mail addresses. Why was that?

Comment: This Might be problem with your SMTP

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala But why this happens to specific email addresses?